# C# TabControl переключение вкладок

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

В проекте вместо стандартного TabControl'а использую UltraTabControl от Infragistics. Есть проблема с изменением выбранной вкладки: после задания выбранной вкладки у UltraTabControl'а в коде срабатывает событие `SelectedTabChanged`, к этому моменту уже должна быть выбрана и отрисована соответствующая вкладка, но когда я отображаю TabControl через `BringToFront()`, **на секунду я вижу последнюю выбранную вкладку**. Вот код:

```
private void ShowTabPage(int index)
{
    if (ultraTabControl.SelectedTab.Index == index) ultraTabControl.BringToFront();
    else ultraTabControl.SelectedTab = ultraTabControl.Tabs[index];
}
// Событие, которое срабатывает после изменения вкладки
private void tabSteps_SelectedTabChanged(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.SelectedTabChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // При первой загрузке приложения срабатывает это событие
    if (!isFirstLoading)
    {
        ultraTabControl.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

P.S. Аналогичная проблема с DevExpress XtraTabControl v11.2, значит, дело не в веб-контроле. На форме у меня есть следующий код для красивой отрисовки контролов, может он как-то на это влияет?

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED  
        if (this.IsXpOr2003 == true)
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00080000; // Turn on WS_EX_LAYERED
        return cp;
    }
}

private Boolean IsXpOr2003
{
    get
    {
        OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
        Version vs = os.Version;
        if (os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
            if (((vs.Major == 6) || (vs.Major == 5)) && (vs.Minor != 0))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"может, он как-то на это влияет?"_ -- попробуйте его убрать. закоментить свойство `protected override CreateParams ...`

Comment: убрал, результат такой же

Comment: создал тестовое приложение, там последняя вкладка не отображается после переключения

Comment: а не проще сделать так: `void ShowTabPage(int index) { ultraTabControl.SelectedIndex = index; ultraTabControl.BringToFront(); }`

Comment: изначально так и было. я полагал, что я вижу последнюю открытую вкладку потому, что вызываю BringToFront() до того, как произошло переключение вкладки. поэтому я подписался на событие SelectedTabChanged, в котором вызываю BringToFront()

Comment: Попробуйте таки использовать в полной мере MVVM. То вместо void ShowTabPage(int index) используйте биндинг в xaml.

Comment: @iRumba - вопрос про WinForms

Answer (score 0):

BringToFront выводит Ваш ultraTabControl на передний план.
Я бы попробывал так:

```
private void ShowTabPage(int index)
{
   // Call BeginUpdate to prevent the display from refreshing.
   // Note: This MUST be paired with a call to
   // EndUpdate below.
   this.ultraTabControl.BeginUpdate();
   
  this.ultraTabControl.SelectedTab = ultraTabControl.Tabs[index];

    // Call EndUpdate to allow the display to refresh
    this.ultraTabControl.EndUpdate();
 
}
```

Событие `tabSteps_SelectedTabChanged` можно использовать для отладки (см. документацию производителя):

```
private void ultraTabControl1_SelectedTabChanged(object sender, 
 Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.SelectedTabChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("The tab with text '" + e.Tab.Text + "' has been 
    selected");

  if ( e.PreviousSelectedTab != null )
       Debug.WriteLine("The previous selected tab was: " + 
  e.PreviousSelectedTab.ToString());    
}
```